# Selenium: Multi browser parallel testing

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome, selenium, chat

I'm trying to test a chat application and I have been facing a specific problem. The idea is the following:

1. My first user opens a chat and sends an invitation
2. The second receives the invitation that opens the chat panel
3. Once both are online they can start the chat.

I have developed the test script on selenium IDE and I have set up the Selenium RC and the Selenium HUB up and running for both test. Also, I have run my test on Eclipse checking that everything is going smoothly (using Javascript).

The thing is that my first test needs to wait at a specific moment for the second test to start and I don't know how to do it.
I use the waitForElementPresent to wait for the response of the other user on the chat room, but the second test case never starts because it is waiting for the first one to finish.

I don't know if I make myself clear but I really need help... I have been reading a lot of threads and nothing comes close to help me.

I have notice that if I stop one test case I will lose my session to start the second test case and I want it to remain on in order to simulate the chat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JUnitCore.runClasses(ParallelComputer.methods(), YourClassWithTests.class);
```

Try this, it should run both tests simultaneously. Running tests concurrently won't get any easier.

Or just mix the two tests together:

```
Selenium sele1 = new DefaultSelenium(something);
Selenium sele2 = new DefaultSelenium(something);
sele1.open("http://google.com");
sele2.open("http://seleniumhq.org");
```

This should open two browsers in one test, you should be able to control them both without a problem.